# How to use Android Room on entities without fields?

Tags: android, android-room

I have java objects which are are backed by a HashMap and thus do not have plain fields which can be discovered via reflection. For example:

```
public class City {
    private final HashMap<String, String> internalMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public String getId() {
        return internalMap.get("id");
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        internalMap.put("id", id);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return internalMap.get("name");
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        internalMap.put("name", name);
    }
}
```

I want to use classes such as this an entity in Room without having to change its structure since I have many such classes which are auto-generated using code generation tools and there are specific reasons why they need to be backed by a HashMap. Each value of the HashMap should end up as a column in my database table (the key String is an internal implementation detail). Is it possible? Seems not to be at the moment due to how fields are discovered by the annotation processor.

**UPDATE:**

None of the answers were at all what I was looking for. I opened a new question without mentioning HashMap since that detail was not supposed to be relevant but all the answers latched on to it. See [How to use Android Room with POJOs provided by an external library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57170881/how-to-use-android-room-with-pojos-provided-by-an-external-library) for the updated question.

Comment: "Is it possible?" -- I can't think of a way for accomplishing this. However, I encourage you to think of Room entities as data transfer objects (DTOs), the same way that you might think of the POJOs that you use to model Web service responses for use with Retrofit. IOW, if `City` is a model object being used by the UI, IMHO `City` should not be a Room entity. Room, Web services, and the like impose limitations (e.g., relations for Room) that constrain the DTOs. Map the DTO data to/from idealized model objects that simplify your UI and business logic work in the app.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. I presume by "Map the DTO data to/from idealized model objects" you mean I would need to write another class perhaps named `CityEntity` with real Java fields and then write functions to copy all the relevant data between the objects and call them depending on whether I am storing or loading City instances. It seems rather tedious but maybe I could use code generation and or reflection to eliminate the need to write a bunch of boilerplate converters.

Comment: Either that, or perhaps Room is not the right solution for you. Room and other ORMs lean towards working with objects that have their data in first-class fields, rather than using a `HashMap` as an indirection. If you move to Kotlin, it is possible that you might be able to get "the best of both worlds" by using delegated properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TypeConverter for this.
For instance, you can use serialization provided by GSON to easily convert the map to serialized state and vice versa.

```
class MapConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    public String fromMap(HashMap<String, String> map) {
        return new Gson().toJson(map);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public HashMap<String, String> fromString(String serializedMap) {
        Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>(){}.getType();
        return gson.fromJson("serializedMap", type);
    }
}
```

And in your entity class:

```
@Entity
@TypeConverters({MapConverter.class})
public class CityEntity {
//...
private final HashMap<String, String> internalMap;
//...
}
```

So the converter will be available for this entity to serialize the hashmap to string and vice versa.
Gson is just a possible solution, you can actually use whatever you want.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all. It's also really unclear why I need or want Gson. I want each of my fields (imagine I have both an id and name) to be persisted in their own columns, I don't want json in my table. Also your type converters both return String. When attempt to compile I get a bunch of errors. My Dao class can't find any of the fields `id` or `name`.

Comment: @satur9nine this is actually the correct (and probably only) approach when you have something like your datamodel, where it can't be changed to an `Entity`. Apart from that, a `Map` for what it's worth is basically just the same as a Json array of keys and values.
If you don't like the approach with serialising your `Map` into a Json object, you have to find another way of creating your datamodel as Entities only support primitive types because behind the scenes it's just SQLite.
Just to clarify: a TypeConverter converts complex objects to primitive objects (in this case a String).

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear... I am not really interested in storing the map, the map is just an internal mechanism for storing plain Strings. The point is I have getters and setters for the fields, they simply are backed by something other than an actual Java field.

Comment: @satur9nine so you want to migrate from your `Map` version into a Room `Entity`? If so, you need to make the migration manually, so create a `City` class with backing properties and assign them from your `Map` and then save them to Room. You can still put the map inside your `City` class, but for simplicity for now I'd recommend not doing it. If you really want to put it inside the `City` you need to mark the `Map` with `@Ignore` so Room doesn't try to process it.

Comment: @satur9nine, for Map.Entry members to end up as a separated columns in a table of the database the simpliest solution is to separate persistence layer model from domain. if I understood correctly, you can create a CityEntity that is described by id and name fields and create mechanisms (just conversion methods as the simpliest solution) to convert your domain object into room-satisfiable representation and vice versa, so your City will end up with collection of CityEntities, where you will have CityEntities collection size equal to Citi'es internal hashmap's size.

Answer (score 0):

Room has it's own set of [annotations](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data) - and if you do not want to have a field mapped, you have to indicate this towards the annotation processor by annotating the POJO as it may be required; eg. `@Entity` without assigning a `tableName`, as well the `@Ignore` above the field to ignore:

```
@Entity
public class City {

    @Ignore
    private final HashMap<String, String> internalMap = new HashMap<>();

    /* concerning the second part of the question: */
    public HashMap<String, Object> toHashMap() {
        return this.internalMap;
    }
}
```

besides those getters have the fundamental problem, that they assume all the keys would exist, despite the `HashMap` might not have been populated with all (or any) of those keys. and it's [absurd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) to represent a city with two different types of object - while one has full control over which fields are being mapped and which are being ignored (one possible approach does not have to exclude the other here)... a method to return the `HashMap` might be useful, eg. in order to insert that into Firebase.

I'd rather go for fields holding the values, while nevertheless being able to return a `HashMap`:

```
@Entity(tableName = "cities")
public class City {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "cityId")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int cityId = -1;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "cityName")
    private String cityName = null;

    ...

    /* concerning the second part of the question: */
    public HashMap<String, Object> toHashMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
        if(this.cityId   !=   -1) {values.put(  "id", this.cityId);}
        if(this.cityName != null) {values.put("name", this.cityName);}
        return values;
    }
}
```

such a `toHashMap()` method also provides control, which fields the returned `HashMap` shall contain, while the example with the `TypeConverter` & `GSON` would (as it is) convert the whole `HashMap`.