# How to use Android Room with POJOs provided by an external library?

Tags: android, android-room

This is a clarification of my previous question [How to use Android Room on entities without fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902935/how-to-use-android-room-on-entities-without-fields).

My use case is that I am using a Java JAR library provided by a third party which contains many POJOs that I want to store and retrieve via Android Room. Clearly I cannot annotate the fields in a class that I don't have the source code for. The internal structure of the POJOs provided is a black box, all I have access to are setters and getters.

Imagine for example I want to use instances of `android.graphics.Rect` with Room.

Comment: Wrap each of the original POJOs in a new POJO containing the required annotations.

Comment: Is the state of the POJO determinable through the getters? Put another way, if you were to use the getters to set attributes of another instance of the object would those two objects effectively be the same?

Comment: @Synergi Correct, the library POJO has setters and getters and no other exposed state.

Comment: @satur9nine I believe in the case you're describing, your best course of action would be writing an entity model object that represents the POJO you want to store by the values from it's setters and a utility function to map your Room entity object back to the library POJO. Otherwise the only other option I can think of now is Blundell's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are solutions I came up with, none is completely ideal but the last is decent.

**Bad:**

This option is just naively making a copy of the library POJO class and providing helper methods to convert the the Library POJO to and from the Room POJO. Pretty ugly and since this makes copies that can diverge and get out of sync and I have to write a lot of code copying back and forth in my app.

```
@Entity(tableName = "items")
public class RoomItem {

  @PrimaryKey
  @NonNull
  public String id;
  public String name;
  public Long price

  public LibraryItem to() {
    LibraryItem li = new LibraryItem();
    li.setName(name);
    li.setPrice(price);
  }

  public static RoomItem from(LibraryItem li) {
    RoomItem ri = new RoomItem();
    ri.name = li.getName();
    ri.price = li.getPrice();
  }

}
```

**Okay:**

In this case the `RoomItem` is a wrapper class with fields that are only used to inform Room about the columns and types, other than `id` nothing is every actually stored in the fields so they just waste space. Any time I want to get the real library object for use with library methods I have to grab the wrapped instance. At least the RoomItem and LibraryItem actually mirror changes.

```
@Entity(tableName = "items")
public class RoomItem {

  // I have to put these fields here even though they aren't used to store any
  // data just to make Room happy!
  @PrimaryKey
  @NonNull
  private String id = "";
  private String name;
  private Long price;

  @Ignore
  private final LibraryItem item = new LibraryItem();

  public RoomItem(String id, String name, Long price) {
    this.id = id;
    setName(name);
    setPrice(price);
  }

  @NonNull
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(@NonNull String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return item.getName();
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    item.setName(name);
  }

  public Long getPrice() {
    return item.getPrice();
  }

  public void setPrice(Long price) {
    item.setPrice(price);
  }

  public Library getLibraryItem() {
    return item;
  }
}
```

**Better (2.2.0-alpha02 or later)**

[Google fixed a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138238182) I reported in Room and as of 2.2.0-alpha02 it is now possible to use inheritance. The fields in the child class are just used to inform Room what to persist and when `minify` is enabled they are actually culled so no memory is wasted. This solution required me to know a bit about the internal structure of the parent class so I could ignore things inside it such as `privateParentField`. However it's better than the "Okay" example because I can now pass instances of the `RoomItem` around to methods that take `LibraryItem` and I don't need to write much boilerplate.

```
@Entity(tableName = "items", ignoredColumns = "privateParentField")
public class RoomItem extends LibraryItem {

  // I have to put these fields here even though they aren't used to store any
  // data just to make Room happy!
  @PrimaryKey
  @NonNull
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private Long price;

  public RoomItem(String id, String name, Long price) {
    setId(id);
    setName(name);
    setPrice(price);
  }

}
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the latest fix from Google in 2.2.0-alpha02 which I reported in response to my troubles.

Comment: OK, do you have mentioned two classes - POJO and ROOM? I would like to compare them. I am getting such error: `error: Field has non-unique column name.`.

Comment: @deadfish POJO is an acronym for "plain old java class" it typically means a normal java class that doesn't extend another class. Room is not a class it is the name of a software library written by Google, see here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: Hello, I understand the basics but I would like to check out your mentioned classes (or I misunderstood something). It would be great if I could use one class instead of two (pojo and room) when I work with them - especially when I load pojo and then I must insert to database. Maybe you have any other example on gist?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the embedded Annotation

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Embedded

> Can be used as an annotation on a field of an Entity or Pojo to signal that nested fields (i.e. fields of the annotated field's class) can be referenced directly in the SQL queries.

Library:

```
class BlackBox {
  String foo
}
```

Your code:

```
@Entity
class MyWhiteBox {

  @Embedded
  private BlackBox blackbox 

}
```

Room will consider `foo` as if is is a field of the `MyWhiteBox` class when mapping an SQLite row to Address.

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me. I don't want Room to treat the library POJO as embedded in a POJO I write myself. In your example `MyWhiteBox` needs a primary key to make Room happy but I don't want to add additional fields to the library POJO, I just want to use the getters and setters that are in library POJO for various columns including the primary key I don't want to add any additional columns.

Comment: having your primary key controlled by a library / another module that is not aware it is being used as a database primary key will end up with very coupled/buggy/undeterministic (not clean!) code. Bite the bullet and handle your own POJO's for your own database. Or use the annotations in the library module.

Comment: If I could add specify my own id to the Library POJO somehow that would be acceptable (wrapping or subclassing or something else)? I most importantly need a way to control which fields are stored or not in the Library POJO without being able to annotate the Library POJO.